# laravel exclude a word from route slug

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

hello I'm using backpack page manager and the auth route logout is conflicting with it

[image]

as u can see in the picture it's assuming that logout is a page with a slug and trying to get its data.

I tried to exclude the 'logout' from the pages route slug but didn't work

My failed attempt:

```
 Route::get('/{page:slug}', [SiteController::class, 'singlePage'])
    ->where('slug', '^(?!logout).*$')
    ->name('single_page');
```

Comment: Laravel's default `logout` method accepts POST request and shouldn't make issue with GET request of same URL. Execute `php artisan route:list` to check all defined routes.

Comment: Also it is better to define all routes with hardcoded routes first, after define the generic routes with slugs, variables etc. then the correct pages will always work.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure Auth routes comes first.
That's most probably the issue.

```php
// Auth
Auth::routes();

...

// Pages
Route::get('/{page:slug}', [SiteController::class, 'singlePage'])
    ->name('single_page');
```

*Side Note*
Take a look at [Laravel Backpack Page Manager](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PageManager), it may be enough for what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think `slug` should be `page`

```
->where('slug', '^(?!logout).*$')
```

should be

```
->where('page', '^(?!logout).*$')
```